# Finding vertices of a rhombus in complex plane

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, euclidean-geometry

> If $A,B,C,D$ are the vertices of a rhombus and $M$ is the point of intersection of the diagonals such that $2AC=BD$, find the vertex $A$ if $D$ is $1+i$ and $M$ is $2-i$.

**Attempt:**

$$MA\perp MD$$
$$MA\times MD=\pm i\vert MA\vert\cdot\vert MD\vert$$
$MD=\sqrt{5}$ and $MA=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$

Let $A$ be $a+bi$

After taking the cross product, $4a+2b-11=0$ or $4a+2b-1=0$

How should I proceed?

Comment: what is rhombus useful?

Comment: Diagonals bisect each other

Comment: how about $AB=BC=CD=DA$?

Comment: Then I will have to find all the vertices.

Comment: you know $AD$,try to use it.

Comment: Is it $\frac{5+35i}{96}$

Comment: No. There are two possible values of A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translating the problem with the vector $i-2$ we obtain $M=0$ and $D=2i-1$. Because $B$ is symmetric to $D$ (respect to $M$), then $B=1-2i$.
Now, the symmetric of $B$ respect to axis x has the same modulo and is $1+2i$, because $2AC=BD$ we obtain that $C=\frac{1+2i}{2}$ and $A$ is the symmetric of $C$, $ A=\frac{-1-2i}{2}$.

Finally, translating to original position (adding 2-i) we obtain the solution.

Comment: you can change A to C and is the same

Comment: A can have two possible values. But can you help me solve the question using my method? (If its possible)

Comment: By the way, that's not the answer given.

Comment: Did you add 2-i?

Comment: I did. I think the given answer is wrong. Your method seems correct.